# BERT Convert 'SpanAnnotation' to answers using scores from hugging face models

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm following along with the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforquestionanswering) for importing a pretrained model question and answer model from huggingface

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForQuestionAnswering
import torch
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
question, text = "Who was Jim Henson?", "Jim Henson was a nice puppet"
inputs = tokenizer(question, text, return_tensors='pt')
start_positions = torch.tensor([1])
end_positions = torch.tensor([3])
outputs = model(**inputs, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
loss = outputs.loss
start_scores = outputs.start_logits
end_scores = outputs.end_logits
```

this returns start and end scores, but how can I get a meaningful text answer from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did a little digging around and it looks like scores can be converted to tokens which can be used to build the answer.  Here is a short example:

```
answer_start = torch.argmax(start_scores) 
answer_end = torch.argmax(end_scores) + 1

tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs["input_ids"][0][answer_start:answer_end]))
```

Comment: Right, QA is also called 'span annotation' so the logits are basically giving you the index location for where to find the answer. That is why you get start and end logits -- the model telling you where it thinks the start of the answer begins in the text and where the end of the answer is in the text.

Comment: @JohnStud Yeah, its weird I would think the process would be the same for the Albert models but it looks like some of the method calls aren't normalized, so when using the other tokenizers you follow slightly different flows